# Is there an alert box or Console.log in TestComplete?

Tags: javascript, jscript, testcomplete

If i want to output something to the screen how would i do this using the Jscript scripts. Im used to using alert or console.log neither of which work. Is there a way to just print something to the screen to help me debug?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BuiltIn.ShowMessage("Hello govna");
```

Does the trick

Also something else that was useful is[This Message Dialog where you can add some buttons to your output statements](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/31335/)